# Implementing Critical Section requests in Java

Tags: java, critical-section

I'm creating a replicated file system for a programming assignment that makes use of mutual exclusion.

Idea is: 3 server nodes, 6 client nodes. Clients send WRITE requests to the servers, which are holding copies of the replicated text file. Each node sits on its own machine in a virtual network and I'll be using Java sockets for them to talk to each other.

Problem: How should I handle clients making requests to enter the critical section? I'm using the Ricart-Agrawala Algorithm where a client that wants to enter the section asks the three servers for permission.

Firstly, how exactly should the client model this request? Should I make a request object? Just a boolean array?

Secondly, how should the server nodes handle a request queue, and how should they give a given client permission over a socket connection? I guess the client could send a "finished" message to the servers after it finishes, and then once the server receives that it checks the request queue? Which could just be a Queue based on the ID of the node making the request. Remove the head of the queue then send a message to the node that made the request?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think it might be easier, if you use algorithm to elect one of the nodes as a master/coordinator.

Comment: Perhaps, but we are required to use the Ricart-Agrawala algorithm for mutual exclusion. With a couple of optimizations, but otherwise exactly the same.

Comment: First time I've actually ever heard about that algorithm, but after reading about it from wiki it seems rather simple. Just send the request to server nodes and wait until you get replies. When/if you get the replies, you may start processing the locked resource (you may choose to continue, if over 50% of nodes reply - in your case 2 out of 3) When the processing is done, send an acknowledgment to the server nodes (again, you must reach over 50% of total nodes) I think I would use some form of 2 phase commit protocol to ensure that there won't be any conflicts.

Comment: I'm going to require unanimous permission rather than just a majority. The problem I'm having though is actual implementation. You say "Send the request to server nodes and wait until you get replies". I say, "What is the request? What is the reply? From a code standpoint."

I'm not an advanced Java programmer, and have virtually zero experience with sockets.